# "Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified" in Jmeter

Tags: oracle, jmeter

When I run a jmeter script with a JDBC connection I have the following error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

I can connect to the database with sqldeveloper and the query

```
SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL;
```

returns

```
RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.AL32UTF8
```

How need to configure Jmeter that it works?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter locale doesn't match Oracle locale.

1. Figure out what does Oracle use - the most straightforward way is checking what does `NLS_LANG` variable stand for
2. Configure JMeter to use that language and the relevant country by:

   - adding next 2 lines to *system.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

     ```
     user.language=en
     user.country=US
     ```

   You may need to change "user.language" to `ru` and "user.country" to `RU` or whatever according to what you figure out from NLS_LANG variable
3. Restart  JMeter to pick the properties up

Alternative way of passing "user.country" and "user.lang" properties is using -D command line arguments, like:

```
jmeter -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -n -t /path/to/test.jmx ...
```

References:

- [ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified](https://community.oracle.com/thread/430906?tstart=0)
- [How do I set the default locale via System properties?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-via-system-properties.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Does the NLS_LANG parameter check from SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS? If yes then NLS_LANGUAGE = RUSSIAN , NLS_TERRITORY = RUSSIA for me, but when I set user.language=ru
user.country=RU in system.properties it doesn't work.

Comment: I run jmeter via runJmeterUI.sh

Comment: C:/apache-jmeter/bin/jmeter -p jmeter.properties -Duser.country=RU -Duser.language=ru -q /sanbox-template=localhost:9080 it doesn't work too.

Comment: The same situation with US and en

Answer (score 0):

I added the NLS_LANG variable in the environment in windows and it worked!

1. Determine the NLS_LANG value.

In the data warehouse database, run the command

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS
```

Make a note of the NLS_LANG value, which is in the format [NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET].

For Windows:

2. Navigate to Control Panel > System and click the Advanced tab. Click Environment Variables.
3. In System variables section, click New.
4. In the Variable Name field, enter NLS_LANG.
5. In the Variable Value field, enter the NLS_LANG value that was returned in Step 1.

For example: American_America.UTF8

6. Reboot the machine after creating the variable.

For Unix set the variable like this:

```
setenv NLS_LANG <NLS_LANG>
```

For more information check the following link: [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I finally find that my Oracle version is 19c, but my OJDBC driver is `ojdbc14.jar`, which is not suitable for Oracle 19c. So I download the latest OJDBC driver for Oracle Database and replace it; after that, the problem is solved.